# No playback buttons when animating in Graph Editor or Dope Sheet

Tags: interface

The small playback buttons when viewing "Timeline" vanish when in the Graph Editor or the Dope Sheet.  Is there a way (other than hotkeys) to bring that little strip of buttons back.  There is room for them.

Comment: you mean the Play button? No it is not available in the Dopesheet or Graph Editor, you need to press the spacebar, but maybe Timeline and Dopesheet windows will be merged in the futur?

Comment: I have spacebar set for menu.  I know I can use hotkeys but I think that playback buttons should be available in these views considering they still show the timeline. I was hoping it would be a switch or a toggle somewhere, maybe even some python script could do it, not sure.

Comment: with ctrl tab you can switch from timeline to graph editor or from dopesheet to graph editor. I remember the merging of dopesheet and timeline was discussed, I don't know what has been decided, it would make sense

Comment: Ctrl+Tab is useful, thanks.I noticed that the "animation" tab creates a miniature timeline view at the bottom of the screen to get around this issue too so I think they at least know about this UI oddity.